# I want to make rust's for statement multithreaded

Tags: multithreading, rust

I would like to change the following function to parallel processing.

```rust
fn cal_v(c: &Array3<f32>, dt: f32) -> Array3<f32> {
  let mut v: Array3<f32> = Array::zeros(c.raw_dim());
  for time in 1..c.shape()[0] {
    let before = c.slice(s![time-1, .., ..]).to_owned();
    let now = c.slice(s![time, .., ..]).to_owned();
    let now_v = (before - now) / dt;
    v.slice_mut(s![time, .., ..]).assign(&now_v);
  }
  v
}
```

The function c is a 3-dimensional array where the first dimension is the index for time, the second dimension is the index for the particle number, and the third dimension is x,y,z.
Personally, I want to learn how to write multi-threaded code,
I want to learn how to make it multithreaded, so I want to do the `for time in 1..c.shape()[0]` part multithreaded.
I believe that this process can be parallelized or made asynchronous because there is no dependency in the process at any index of `for`.
What is the best way to write this?

The version of the compiler I'm using is `1.51.0`.
The version of the library I'm using is `ndarray(0.14.0)`.

Comment: Have a look at [rayon](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon), this looks like a textbook usecase. Side note: are you sure you need to use vectors in your operation ? There may be more to gain by sticking to slices than by parallelizing.

Comment: If you want a more precise answer a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will be needed. The usual solution in Rust for building MRE is the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to parallelize an iteration is to just use [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/index.html), that's basically its bread and butter. You will have to convert the loop to a more functional style (using `for_each` for the final loop body), but with that done `par_iter()` will "magically" distribute the work over its threadpool.

There is an issue I'm not too clear about though because you don't provide any of the code:

```rust
v.slice_mut(s![time, .., ..]).assign(&now_v);
```

is a hard sequential dependency between all the items as-is, and I've no idea what the `s` macro does, so it may or may not be workable. If each `time` yields a single slot from `v` (or at least non-overlapping slots) you would be able to `zip` the iterators together such that each iteration has a "source" and a "destination" independent from all the others, otherwise you'd have a sequential choke-point in the output, which [isn't something rayon supports well](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/issues/210).

Comment: `v.slice_mut(s![time, .., ..]).assign(&now_v)` involves assigning now_v to the time part of the first dimension of v.